# Parsing huge data coming from a URL

Tags: java, performance, strings, parsing

I need to parse the data coming from the URL which looks like this:

```
hasProcess=true
version=1
DATACENTER=abc
    TotalNumberOfServers:4
    primary:{0=1, 1=2, 2=1, 3=2, 4=1, 5=2, 6=1, 7=2, 8=1, 9=2, 10=1, 11=2, 12=1, 13=2}
    secondary:{0=0, 1=0, 2=0, 3=1, 4=0, 5=0, 6=0, 7=1, 8=0, 9=0, 10=0, 11=1, 12=0, 13=0}
    hosttomachine:{3=machineA, 2=machineB, 1=machineC, 4=machineD}
DATACENTER=pqr
    TotalNumberOfServers:2
    primary:{0=1, 1=2, 2=1, 3=2, 4=1, 5=2, 6=1, 7=2, 8=1, 9=2, 10=1, 11=2, 12=1, 13=2, 14=1}
    secondary:{0=0, 1=0, 2=0, 3=1, 4=0, 5=0, 6=0, 7=1, 8=0, 9=0, 10=0, 11=1, 12=0, 13=0, 14=0}
    hosttomachine:{1=machineP, 4=machineQ}
DATACENTER=tuv
    TotalNumberOfServers:0
    primary:{}
    secondary:{}
    hosttomachine:{}
```

After parsing the data I need to store each datacenter data in a `Map` like this:

```
HashMap<String, Map<Integer, String>> primaryData
```

For example, the Key of `primaryData` is `abc` and value is:

```
{0=1, 1=2, 2=1, 3=2, 4=1, 5=2, 6=1, 7=2, 8=1, 9=2, 10=1, 11=2, 12=1, 13=2}
```

which is for primary.

Similarly another `Map` for secondary for each datacenter:

```
HashMap<String, Map<Integer, String>> secondaryData
```

For example, the Key of `secondaryData` is `abc` and value is:

```
{0=0, 1=0, 2=0, 3=1, 4=0, 5=0, 6=0, 7=1, 8=0, 9=0, 10=0, 11=1, 12=0, 13=0}
```

which is for secondary.

And lastly, one more map for `hosttomachine` mapping for each datacenter:

```
HashMap<String, Map<Integer, String>> hostMachineMapping -
```

For example, the Key of `hostMachineMapping` is `abc` and value is:

```
{3=machineA, 2=machineB, 1=machineC, 4=machineD}
```

which is for `hosttomachine`.

And all the above map will have data for its datacenter as I have three datacenter in the above example. So each each map will have three data. And also I will parse the above response only when `hasProcess` is equal to `true`. If it is not true, then I won't parse anything.

This code takes more than 200 ms to parse the data and store it in its corresponding `HashMap`. Is there any way to parse the above data efficiently and store it in particular `HashMap`?

```
private void parseResponse(String response) throws Exception {
    if (response != null) {
        Map<String, Map<Integer, String>> primaryData = null;
        Map<String, Map<Integer, String>> secondaryData = null;
        Map<String, Map<Integer, String>> hostMachineMapping = null;

        long version = 0L;
        boolean changed = false;
        String splitResponse[] = response.split("DATACENTER=");

        boolean flag = false;
        for (String sr : splitResponse) {
            if (!flag) {
                flag = true;
                String[] header = sr.split("\n");
                changed = Boolean.parseBoolean(header[0].split("=")[1]);
                if (!changed) {
                    return;
                } else {
                    version = Integer.parseInt(header[1].split("=")[1]);
                    primaryData = new HashMap<String, Map<Integer, String>>();
                    secondaryData = new HashMap<String, Map<Integer, String>>();
                    hostMachineMapping = new HashMap<String, Map<Integer, String>>();
                }
            } else {
                generateDataCenterMapping(sr, primaryData, secondaryData, hostMachineMapping);
            }
        }

        if (changed) {
            Mapping.setPrimaryData(primaryData);
            Mapping.setSecondaryData(secondaryData);
            Mapping.setHostMachineMapping(hostMachineMapping);
            Mapping.setVersion(version);
        }
    }
}

private void generateDataCenterMapping(String sr, Map<String, Map<Integer, String>> primaryData,
                            Map<String, Map<Integer, String>> secondaryData,
                            Map<String, Map<Integer, String>> hostMachineMapping) throws Exception {

    String[] data = sr.split("\n\t");
    String dcName = data[0];
    int numOfServers = Integer.parseInt(data[1].split(":")[1]);
    if (numOfServers > 0) {
        primaryData.put(dcName, generateMap(data[2]));
        secondaryData.put(dcName, generateMap(data[3]));
        hostMachineMapping.put(dcName, generateMap(data[4]));
    }
}

private Map<Integer, String> generateMap(String map) throws Exception {
    String tableString = map.split(":")[1];
    Map<Integer, String> table = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
    tableString = tableString.substring(1, tableString.length() - 1);
    String[] entries = tableString.split(", ");

    for (String e : entries) {
        String[] entryVal = e.split("=");
        table.put(Integer.parseInt(entryVal[0]), entryVal[1]);
    }

    return table;
}
```

Comment: What's the name of the class with this `parseResponse` method? Does it not have any public members?

Comment: Since your code is not about the getting of the data, then it actually does not matter where it comes from, so that detail should not be included prominently in the question title.

Comment: This data format looks like [tag:yaml], but it isn't. Do you also have control over the server, and could you make it emit YAML instead?

Answer (score 6):

I started to write a comment, but it became too long.

#### Questions

- 200 ms is pretty close to eternity, how long is your input?
- Can you measure how long `parseResponse` alone takes?
- Could you post your data? Someone may try harder to optimize.

#### Potential slowness causes

I guess your `String.split` could be the culprit (with more than one character a regex gets created; you should use

```
 private static final Pattern COMMA_BLANK_PATTERN = Pattern.compile(", ");
```

for splitting and use split limit of 2. Probably faster could be using Guava's

```
private static final Splitter COMMA_BLANK_SPLITTER = Splitter.on(", ");
```

Even better would be piece-wise processing instead of splitting.

Note also that `Integer.parseInt` is internationalized and therefore slightly slower than necessary. Probably unimportant.

#### Review

```
if (response != null) {
```

As Mat's Mug said, this is wrong. I'm using Guava's `Preconditions` with a static import writing simply

```
checkNotNull(response);
```

This makes it fail-fast rather than hiding the problem to bite you later.

---

```
String tableString = map.split(":")[1];
Map<Integer, String> table = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
tableString = tableString.substring(1, tableString.length() - 1);
```

This is pretty confusing by squeezing something else between the two `tableString` defining lines.

#### Summary

Overall, it's not bad. When speed is important, I'd go for something like

```
MyParser parser = new MyParser(response).skip("hasProcess=");
boolean hasProcess = parser.readBoolean();
parser.skip("\nversion=");
int version = parser.readInt();
while (parser.skipIfLookingAt("\nDATACENTER=")) {
     parser.parseDatacenter(parser, whatever...);
}
```

It's just an idea (damn similar to `java.util.Scanner`, which isn't exactly known for speed), but I guess that string splitting is the problem (simply as I can't see anything else).

An example method could look like

```
MyParser skip(String prefix) {
    for (int i=0; i<prefix.length(); ++i) {
        if (content.charAt(index++) != prefix.charAt(i)) {
             throw ...
        }
    }
}
```

where `content` and `index` are instance variables. This part doesn't need any substring creation at all (and gets a bit unreadable because of this). **Warning:** Doing something like `content = content.substring(index)` (so you could use `startsWith`) would make it clearer but terribly slow as you'd copy a big part of the string a lot of times.

#### Filling the maps

Now, I'd probably move all the functionality into `MyParser`, so that the parsing would be just

```
 private void parseResponse(String response) {
     new MyParser(response).parse();
 }
```

The parser would have fields like

```
 private final Map<String, Map<Integer, String>> primaryData;
```

so that I could write

```
void parseDatacenter() {
    String datacenter = readTill('\n');
    skip("\n\tTotalNumberOfServers:");
    int totalNumberOfServers = readInt();
    skip("\n\tprimary{");        
    primaryData.put(datacenter, readMap());
    skip("\n\t");
}

Map<String, String> readMap() {
    Map<String, String> result = new HashMap<>();
    while (true) {
         String key = readTillAndSkip('=');
         String value = readTillOneOf("},");
         map.put(key, value);
         if (lookingAt('}') {
             break;
         }
         skip(", ");
    }
    return result;
}
```

As an example see this simple method

```
String readTillOneOf(String terminators) {
    int start = index;
    while (terminators.indexOf(content.charAt(index)) > -1) {
        ++index;
    }
    return content.substring(start, index);
}
```

I ignored quite some details like parsing numbers and I can't tell how many parsing methods you'll need, but basically it's all pretty simple. Just skip what's fixed and process what you want while looking for a terminator.

It could get a bit more complicated if you needed to be error-tolerant, like allowing multiple spaces, but then you could let some of your methods skip over them. Or, if it gets difficult, use regexes. But I don't think it gets complicated.

*Note that I'm unsure why your parser is slow. There's a lot of splitting and this is the probable cause, but it's just a guess.*

Comment: Thanks for the help. Your approach is looking good to me. But I am confuse how do I adapt this to get the actual working solution. If  possible and if you have some time, can you provide an example how will this work with your overall approach?

Comment: @david I don't know good enough what you're doing. I'd just make the three "major" maps to instance variables and let `parseDatacenter` create and fill the per-datacenter maps and put them into the major ones. It should eat the string (i.e. increment `index`) so that the next iteration looks at `"\nDATACENTER"` again. +++ I can write some more code, but chose what part would be most helpful.

Comment: To me important part is, given a string response like as shown in the question, what is the best way to populate those three maps? Since this will set the foundation for me to move forward. If you were to solve this problem, then how would  you do this, your  approach sounds good to me but I was confuse to adapt it to populate three maps.

Comment: @david I've updated the answer. Basically, you need a parser for the map data, which starts just after the opening brace and exits on the closing brace. Then you put the map where it belongs to, eat the brace and other fixed things, etc.

Answer (score 4):

I find it awkward that you're wrapping the entire method's body in an `if` block:

```
if (response != null) {
```

In fact, I find it awkward that you're *doing nothing* with a `null` response, especially given an indicator such as `throws Exception`.

I would expect the method to throw some kind of `ArgumentNullException` (sorry if that's not in Java, I'm a C# guy - I'm sure Java has something similar though) given a `null` response string.

The typical way to do this, is to have a *guard clause* at the start of the method:

```
if (response == null) {
    throw new ArgumentNullException("response");
}
```

And then, go on with the method body, knowing you have a valid `response`. Notice that just eliminated a whole nesting level across the entire method!

---

I find your logic rather convoluted, and I would expect `parseResponse` to *return* an object (or a collection of objects) holding the parsed data... not to have direct (or indirect) side-effects: I think your code is doing too many things.

The fact that `parseResponse` isn't a public member smells IMO, because *parsing a response* is a testable concern of its own, and there should be a class dedicated to making this work, where `parseResponse` would be public. Having it buried as an internal implementation detail of something bigger tells me that the only way you have of testing (and benchmarking) your parsing logic is by running the entire thing - presumably without any way of really knowing how much of the 200ms is actually spent sending the request and receiving the response: you want to be able to feed that method with a "fake" response string, and test-run all edge cases without having to send an actual request to some remote server that could be offline for maintenance while you're running your tests!

Comment: @Mat Thanks for your suggestion. This class is my background thread which runs every 5 minute and it calls another service url from which it gets the above data. Now after parsing that string, I need to set those three maps in my Mapping class so that's why it was void.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, there is quite a bit of fuzziness with respect to the performance issues here. First, what is **actually** taking 200ms? Is it just this method, exclusively? Is it this method plus the external methods it calls (the `Mapping.set*` methods)? Is it the entire request and parsing? Second, has there been any profiling done to narrow down some candidates for what exactly might be the bottleneck? It could be the string manipulation, the `HashMap`, or something else completely. Third, what kind of input are we looking at? There is a sample, but are there hundreds of datacenters or hundreds of thousands? If the number is truly large, 200ms may actually be completely reasonable. There is also the possibility of being bound by some component of the hardware, but we can hand wave that.

Given the constraints listed, here are a few suggestions. They are not tested because of the potential variability of the above. The shape and size of your actual data could lead to significant differences between the suggestions.

---

### Strings

There is obviously a lot of string manipulation going on, particularly `String#split`. [maaartinus goes into some detail](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/94405/38383) on why this can lead to performance troubles, especially if it is using regexes internally. In place of some of the splits, `String#substring`, `String#startsWith`, and `String#endsWith` might be more performant.

It *might* also be faster to handle lines individually using a combination of [`StringReader`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/StringReader.html) and [`BufferedReader`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html), or [`Scanner`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html). Each of these has their own set of performance properties and optimizations to consider. These could even make your code *slower* depending on how they handle things internally, but it might be worth trying them.

---

### HashMaps

`HashMap` is generally a great default choice for a map in Java. It provides `O(1)` insertion and retrieval in most cases. But it does have some quirks. First, if you are putting a lot of data in sequentially, the `HashMap` internally needs to keep growing its internal structures to keep up. This could cause performance problems because each time it grows, it needs to allocate a new chunk of memory, then rehash all the keys to put them into the new chunk. We could instead [just tell `HashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#HashMap%28int%29) what we would like the initial capacity to be, accounting for the load factor, so that this is not an issue. [I have seen data to suggest that this may not be as big of an issue as suggested in the documentation, though.](http://www.javaranch.com/journal/2008/08/supercharging-your-hashmaps.html)

Collisions can also affect the performance of a `HashMap`, but you are using built-in Java objects for keys. Generally, the built-in hashing algorithms produce few collisions on the general set of inputs.

The hashing algorithms themselves, though, may be a bottleneck depending on the shape of your data (the length of the keys). The built-in hashing algorithms are designed to be cheap, but they are not free. There is a possibility that the actual hashing is what is taking so long. This is doubtful, as the algorithms are cheap and the results can be cached, but it is a possibility.

Since you did not post what `Mapping.set*` does, I will make a suggestion based on a *potentiality*. If you are iterating over the `HashMap`s in those methods, you could be experiencing your performance losses in there. Iterating over a `HashMap` is dependent on the *capacity* rather than the number of elements. A `HashMap` with a capacity much larger that the number of elements will slow down.

You can try to vary the type of `Map` you use to see if one of these is affecting the performance. For example, you could use a [`LinkedHashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html) if iteration is the problem. You could test with a [`TreeMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) to see if a completely different structure may actually be more suitable in practice. Because you have two levels of `Map` with different key types, they may each benefit from different optimizations.

---

### Other things

I agree with [@Mat's Mug](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/94395/38383) about using guard clauses to reduce the indentation, and I see more places where similar strategies may be appropriate.

I see you have a variable name `flag`, and I don't like that. It's used awkwardly, and the fact that it has such a nondescript name tells me that it doesn't have a good purpose. Let's look at what it actually does:

> ```
>    boolean flag = false;
>    for (String sr : splitResponse) {
>        if (!flag) {
>            flag = true;
>            String[] header = sr.split("\n");
>            changed = Boolean.parseBoolean(header[0].split("=")[1]);
>            if (!changed) {
>                return;
>            } else {
>                version = Integer.parseInt(header[1].split("=")[1]);
>                primaryData = new HashMap<String, Map<Integer, String>>();
>                secondaryData = new HashMap<String, Map<Integer, String>>();
>                hostMachineMapping = new HashMap<String, Map<Integer, String>>();
>            }
>        } else {
>            generateDataCenterMapping(sr, primaryData, secondaryData, hostMachineMapping);
>        }
>    }
> ```

It is used in the loop to switch behavior. The conditional is a negated conditional with an `else` clause, which is kind of a smell. Generally, I would start by reversing the conditional, but here there's more. Immediately after the conditional, `flag` is set to `true`, and then never set again. I see what this is. This is a "just run me the first time" chunk of code. We can take this out, and just adjust the loop to skip the first iteration.

```
if(splitResponse.length == 0) {
    return;
}

String[] header = splitResponse[0].split("\n");
changed = Boolean.parseBoolean(header[0].split("=")[1]);
if (!changed) {
    return;
}

version = Integer.parseInt(header[1].split("=")[1]);
primaryData = new HashMap<>();
secondaryData = new HashMap<>();
hostMachineMapping = new HashMap<>();

for (int i = 1; i < splitResponse.length; i++) {
    String sr = splitResponse[i];
    generateDataCenterMapping(sr, primaryData, secondaryData, hostMachineMapping);
}
```

I pulled that code out, but I also did a few other things. Because the code is now outside the loop, I had to add a guard to make sure that there is at least one element in the `splitResponse` array. Since the conditional on `!changed` returned, the `else` was superfluous, so I just removed it and un-tabbed the code inside. I also abbreviated the `HashMap` instantiations with the [diamond operator](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2074080/core-java/jdk-7--the-diamond-operator.html)(Java 7+). The loop is much simpler and the boolean `flag` is completely gone.

The `changed` flag can also be eliminated through similar steps.

I might also suggest (though the changes would be more significant) that, instead of having three separate `Map`s, you could create an object to hold the three pieces of data for each key, then have a single map from the key to the object. This would make the association between those data more explicit.